# Combine 2 $_POST into One column using INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that has a hidden field (the date).  I want this data to be inserted with the note that is submitted as well.  I only have 3 columns in my table.  ID,Note_id and Note.

So if a user submits a note the insert statement should add the date infront of the note.

My Current SQL Statement:

```
$pdoOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE, MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASSWORD,$pdoOptions);

$data = [
   'notes' => $_POST['notes'],
   'id' => $_POST['rowID'],
   'date2' => $_POST['date'],
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (note_id, note) Values(:id, :notes)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

My thought was I could add the :date2 to this but it does not seem to work

```
$pdoOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE, MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASSWORD,$pdoOptions);

$data = [
   'notes' => $_POST['notes'],
   'id' => $_POST['rowID'],
   'date2' => $_POST['date'],
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (note_id, note) Values(:id, :date '-' :notes)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Whats the best method of doing this?  I know I can have another column but I dont want that structure.  The way it is displayed on the users side needs to be like this.

Thank you

Comment: Concatenate or assign 2 variables to the 1 variable.

Comment: You cannot concatenate placeholders like you're trying to do. As @FunkFortyNiner says, concatenate the variable used for the second placeholder.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Like this? ``` 'notes' => $_POST['date'] . ": " . $_POST['notes'],```

Comment: More like `$var1= $_POST['var1']; $var2= $_POST['var2']; $var3 = $var1 . "" . $var2;` type of thing, then use `$var3` as part of the array you have now and to use in the binding after. Edit: Or see the answer given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (note_id, note) Values(:id, CONCAT(:date,'-',:notes))";
```

This will work

Comment: `date2` => `date` in your $data